# Динамическая обработка данных из SQL в Excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel

Одна из функций программы: обращение к sql для формирования табличного отчёта в Excel.

Проблема в Excel документе:

1. шапка самой таблицы имеет сложную структуру объединённых ячеек.

Подсказали воспользоваться библиотекой NPOI. Есть ли пример реализации использования этой библиотеки, с целью открыть шаблонный xlsx файл и подменить в нём некоторые ячейки, дабы не громоздить код для разлиновки всей шапки таблицы?

Количество строк таблицы постоянно увеличивается, заранее знать высоту таблицы не представляется возможным. В самом шаблоне столбцы формируют некоторые расчёты с итоговым значением в конце таблицы, т.е. сбивать их не хотелось бы.

Comment: ЧТо значит сложная таблица? Не двумерная что ли?

Comment: Согласен, не лучшая формулировка. Многоуровневая шапка, с элементами объединений ячеек

Comment: Я бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону какого-нибудь решения типа FastReport - накидываешь шаблон, кормишь табличку, получаешь документ. Лишний слой с одной стороны, с другой - никакого ручного забивания гвоздей.

Comment: Проблема только в программном объединении ячеек или нужно что-то еще при построении отчета в Excel-документе?

Comment: Вообще-то Excel умеет работать с шаблонами. Они даже собственное расширение имеют.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток. У нас на проекте была похожая проблема, необходимо было формировать кучу разноплановых отчетов в excel как и у вас с формированием сложных шапок. Для решения вопроса мы использовали библиотеку [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com)
для решения поставленных задач хватало, может и вам поможет:)